# Postfix: Reject outgoing non-existent addresses and addresses not belonging to the user

Tags: postfix, domain

Postfix: How to reject outgoing non-existent addresses and addresses not belonging to the user?

**- Case A: (anything@non-existent-domain.com)**
Logging into Roundcube then create an alias with a non-existent domain name. Then use this to send. It was sending successfully. So I searched on this site and found a solution and it helped.

**- Case B: (non-existent-user@domain.com)**
Logging into Roundcube then create an alias with a non-existent user name. Then use this to send. It sends without getting rejected.

**- Case C: A huge issue: (anything@any-domain-existing-on-machine.com)**
Logging into Roundcube then create an alias with any user's name and using an existent virtual @domain located on the same machine, not belonging to the logged in user. Then send an email with it. It works....

How do I solve Case B and especially Case C?

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
delay_warning_time = 4
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 20480000
milter_default_action = accept
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = domain(*censored*).com
myhostname = domain(*censored*).com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1, VPS-IP (*censored*)
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/path(*censored*)/configs/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.2.2/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$data_directory/smtp_tls_session_cache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_enforce_tls = no
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain(*censored*).com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain(*censored*).com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 2
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
soft_bounce = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/path(*censored*)/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_maps.cf, regexp:/etc/path(*censored*)/configs/postfix/virtual_regexp
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/path(*censored*)/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/path(*censored*)/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/path(*censored*)/configs/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 997
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:997
```

Some values are *censored*.

Answer (score 0):

Well... as a small (Workaround) specifically for Roundcube only which I've seen also done on a major big domain provider with their Roundcube client is to disable the ability to add aliases. Hence not being able to send emails with custom addresses, on roundcube.

By adding this to the Roundcube config: `$config['identities_level'] = 4;`

```
// 0 - many identities with possibility to edit all params
// 1 - many identities with possibility to edit all params but not email address
// 2 - one identity with possibility to edit all params
// 3 - one identity with possibility to edit all params but not email address
// 4 - one identity with possibility to edit only signature

Source: https://forum.iredmail.org/topic10975-iredmail-support-how-to-disable-the-possibility-to-change-sender-identity-in-roundcube.html
```